# How to make a parallax effect with Vanilla JavaScript ES5?

Tags: javascript, parallax

I'm making a parallax effect with Vanilla JS ES5, but I can't seem to make it work.

Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/XZyjXx?editors=0110

The HTML:

```
<section class="page-intro">
    <div class="page-intro__img js-parallax" style="background-image: url(https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/512366437.jpg?w=748&h=498&crop=1);">

    </div>
    <div class="page-intro__overlay"></div>

    <!-- Two Different Parts, big and small -->
    <div class="page-intro__content">
        <h1 class="page-intro__title">Puppy</h1>
        <span class="page-intro__sub-title">Explore how my design process can help your business grow and succeed.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="page-intro__content">

    </div>

</section>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

The JS:

```
    var parallax = document.getElementsByClassName('js-parallax');
    var xScrollPosition;
  var yScrollPosition;

    function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
        el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + ", " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }

  function scrollLoop() {
      xScrollPosition = window.scrollX;
      yScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

      setTranslate(0, yScrollPosition * -0.2, parallax);

  }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollLoop, false);
```

Comment: firstly, what is "vanilla javascript"? secondly, there's so many libraries for parallax effect, either use one, or learn from the code in them - just a suggestion

Comment: @JaromandaX Take a look: [Vanilla Js](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Comment: Oh right ...so, vanilla js is a library - ironic when you think about it :p

Comment: @JaromandaX No it is not. If you just follow the page until the end you'll understand

Comment: Oh yeah. I've actually read that page before

Comment: Yeah, that's why I made this new threat about 'Vanilla JS', without any libraries. I can use libraries, but I want to make one. I want to gain the knowledge, the logic. Yeah, I do learn from the code in them, but the code in there is way too hard, so this is gradual learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really good to see more programmers trying vanilla JS.

You simply have 2 errors.
First you need to make sure the document is loaded before trying to access it's content. You wrap everything in this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    // content loaded
});
```

second

```
document.getElementsByClassName('js-parallax');
```

this does not return an HTML element but an array of elements containing this class. There is only 1 element but it's still an array.

you can solve it by writing

```
document.getElementsByClassName('js-parallax')[0];
```

Comment: I use this: window.onload = function() {} in my projects

Comment: But yes, putting the [0] index worked, hmmmmmmm. But, I have a project where I will use the parallax multiple times, how can I make it global?

Comment: Would I get the length of all items and then add to the event listener and parallax effect?

Comment: first thing i would do is paste the content of setTranslate() into the scrollLoop() function. Then you wrap everything into a function called CreateScrollHandler(className) and then use the input string instead of "js-parallax". Tho i recommend using document.querySelector() to search the dom. Also this is another question. If you'd like in depth discussion you may add my discord.

Comment: the element collection has a length property you can use. Then just use a for loop.